# Scrapy how to add the "query url" as item in the output

Tags: python, scrapy, google-search

i have a list of urls and i import them as start_urls in a scrapy project.
I would like to add in the output the query (url) who generated those results.
For example if i have
"First title results", "Address", etc ----> URL who generated this output.

this is the code i have

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class GmapsclosedlocationsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gmapsclosedlocations'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.google.com']
    
    with open('urls.csv') as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]

    def start_request(self):
        request = Request(url=self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
        yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'name' : response.css('.qrShPb').extract(),
            'closed' : response.css('p.wlxxf::text').extract(),
            'address' : response.css('.LrzXr::text').extract(),
            'phone' : response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "+46")]').extract_first(),
            'website' : response.css('a.ab_button::attr(href)').extract(),
            'firsttitle' : response.css('.DKV0Md::text').extract_first()
        }
```

i would like to have a new item into "yield" that add the url but i have no idea how to do that
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use response.url method to grab each current url inside your yield keyword as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'name' : response.css('.qrShPb').extract(),
            'closed' : response.css('p.wlxxf::text').extract(),
            'address' : response.css('.LrzXr::text').extract(),
            'phone' : response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "+46")]').extract_first(),
            'website' : response.css('a.ab_button::attr(href)').extract(),
            'firsttitle' : response.css('.DKV0Md::text').extract_first(),
            'url': response.url}
```